# sum, least upper bound of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know how to find the sum (not as a decimal number) or the least upper bound of the infinite series

$$\sum_{{k=1}}^{\infty} \frac{(k!)^2}{(k^2)!}$$

Comment: I suppose that you noticed how fast are decreasing the terms.

Comment: a crude application of euler mac laurin formula gives me an approximative value for the sum of $\sqrt{2\pi}/e$ which is not so bad. but i have to think more about it ^^

Answer (score 0):

As correctly observed in the comments, this sum shows a very rapid convergence. Thus, even considering only the first three terms obtained for $k=1,2,3$, we get a partial sum of $$1+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{10080}=\frac{11761}{10080}$$

whose numeric value $1.16676587301...$ shows an error $<3 \cdot 10^{-11}$ when compared with the infinite sum. Adding the fourth term obtained for $k=4$, we can get another fraction whose numerical value $1.16676587304...$ shows an error $<10^{-21}$ when compared with the infinite sum.

Additionally, regardless of the level of approximation, in my opinion there is no particular reason to believe that there exists a strictly closed form for the result of the infinite sum.